# Gitlab: How to show http port in git repo url?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, gitlab

I'm running a gitlab docker image on Ubuntu server. docker is started through a systemd service. the command is:

```
docker run --hostname example  -p 9401:80 -p 9402:443 -p 9403:22  --name gitlab   --volume /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab --volume /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab --env GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG="external_url ='example:9401';gitlab_rails['gitlab_port'] = 9401; gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port']=9403;" example:9104/gitlab/gitlab-ce:10.4.3-ce.0
```

SSH url

```
ssh://git@example:9403/root/test.git
```

HTTP url

```
http://example/root/test.git
```

- How to show http and https port in git url, just like the ssh url? I need port 9401 to be visible in http git url

Comment: 443 and 80 default port and these port not show in url if your port is differnt then try http://example:port/root/test.git

Comment: @Adiii ah ok thank you, I spent all day yesterday trying to make it show. If you are sure of your answer please post it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ssh port is different that's why you mention in URL

`ssh://git@example:9403/root/test.git`.

The default port for `HTTP is`80 and for `HTTPS is`443 so you do not need to mention in URL.

If you Map TCP `port 80` in the container to `port 80` on the Docker host so this will be accessible without mentioning port in the URL.

If you map rather then 80 like you mentioned `9401:80` then you can try something like this.

```
http://example:PORT/root/test.git
```

or

```
http://example:9401/root/test.git
```